# Place button on the top right side of AppBarOverlay

Tags: android

I'm trying to place a button to the right side of AppBarOverlay, I have got it to appear it to the right, but it's below AppBarOverlay text. Below is the image of what it looks like now.

[image]

Instead I want the "clear" button to appear where I have drawn the red circle

Below is my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Verify.AppBarOverlay">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:minHeight="?actionBarSize"
                android:padding="@dimen/appbar_padding"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/clear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:text="Clear"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/status"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#333333"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AppBarLayout is a vertical LinearLayout. So you can't achieve this with AppBarLayout.

For reference https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/appbar/AppBarLayout

You can achieve your desired output by using `Toolbar`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Verify.AppBarOverlay">

           <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
            
           <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:minHeight="?actionBarSize"
                android:padding="@dimen/appbar_padding"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title" />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/clear"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:text="Clear"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/status"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#333333"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```